# Key value pair - regex

Tags: regex

I have a long text with key value pairs separated by a character '•' (ascii 7)
The key must be english letters, digits, and underline - and the value can be everything (also ascii that are not letters)..

The problem I have is that the value can contain '•' as part of its value. Then we need to include it in and and the match should be up to the last '•' of that match.

Manage to do this, but sadly it is not solving my problem.

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+)=((.*?)+)•
```

Test string : `MY_KEY_1=○•◘♠ ♥•MY_KEY_2=as dfa sd f@#$•`

Expected result: 2 matches `MY_KEY_1=○•◘♠ ♥` (NOT `MY_KEY_1=○`) , `MY_KEY_2=as dfa sd f@#$`

Comment: Try [`(\w+)=.*?(?=•\w+=|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/FeXSMe/1)

Comment: `((.*?)+)` is greedy. The external + defeats the internal ?

Comment: Is your string always ended by a `•` as a ending sign, or is the last one part of the second value?

Comment: @Kaddath Not part of the value

Comment: Please specify the language or tool. Lookaheads and character classes vary between engines.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I did not specified it because there are all small adjustments that i can do by myself.. And i think i got already the answer by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483364/2410260)

Comment: I have the general feeling that what you want is not currently possible, how is this case supposed to be handled? a value containing a letter and a `=` sign will be understood as a new key: `•f=` (at least `=` should be forbidden in the value for it to be possible, or something like that)

Comment: of course if part of the value contains english letters and equals and `•` then too bad.. but it is not likely.. only `=` in the value is ok.. and works in the given answer of @revo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't match up to second `•` since it's matching ungreedily and it doesn't have a good ending point. You could try an ungreedy match up to the point where a key name is following:

```
(\w+)=(.*?)(?=•\w+=|$)
```

- `\w` => `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `(?=•\w+=|$)` A positive lookahead that looks for either a key name or end of input string

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/GntxuW/1)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks allot

Comment: note that the last `•` is captured in the last value. Following my other comment, how to handle things like `•f=` in the value? [see here](https://regex101.com/r/hDB8Nj/1)

Comment: @Kaddath Well, why shouldn't it be included? `f` is key name `a s•d f@#$` is its value.

Comment: @revo it means that if `•` can be allowed in a value, `=` shouldn't be allowed, or else it could create a new not wanted key

Comment: @Kaddath Probably OP's sure that such corrupting values will never happen otherwise no concrete structure exists.

Comment: In the end of each match this separator is added (This is how the server is building the long string) - I will simply remove it manually from the last value

Comment: Yes, probably just an implicit rule, just wanted to point out the edge case, you never know

Comment: @RazizaO He's talking about a time when `•f=` appears as value part. Like someone types it there if there are some user inputs.

Comment: The server is adding for sure the last `•` - so it is for sure not part of the value.. the rest `•` that are not the last ones in the group are part of the value.. Anyway, the answer satisfied me and my needs so thumbs up